# 18.04 LTS: No video to Secondary Monitor when on left

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, xps

N00B here:

I have a Dell [XPS 15](https://www.dell.com/support/search/us/en/04#q=XPS15&sort=relevancy&f:iuxType=[Manuals%20%26%20Documentation]&f:product1Facet=[Laptops]&f:langFacet=[en]) running stock Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
I have a secondary monitor which is my old Sony [KDL-32XBR6](https://docs.sony.com/release/specs/kdl32xbr6_mksp.pdf)

Attaching the second monitor works fine IF I leave the Secondary monitor on the right of my laptop in Display Settings.  However, if I move it to the left, then the Sony tells me No Signal.

Issues I have noticed:
1 - Ubuntu tells me I have a Sony 72" - How can I change that?
2 - It doesn't matter if the Sony or the Laptop are set as Primary
3 - Occasionally the green "Apply" button in Display settings will disappear so I can check every resolution to make sure that it isn't a resolution issue.

Any help gratefully received.

```
   model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7660U CPU @ 2.50GHz

   description: Motherboard
   product: 049M47
   vendor: Dell Inc.
   physical id: 0
   version: A00
   serial: /44P5QQ2/CNCMK0087R0007/
   product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7660U CPU @ 2.50GHz
   00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5926 (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])  
   Subsystem: Dell Device 075b
   Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 129
   Memory at db000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
   Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
   I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
   [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
   Capabilities: <access denied>
   Kernel driver in use: i915
   Kernel modules: i915
```

SOLUTION: In Settings go to Thunderbolt
There were 2 pending devices - Dell Thunderbolt cable and dell thunderbolt dock.
These needed to be authorized

Comment: I still haven't found a way to change my screen detection :-(

Comment: Please don't add SOLVED to the title. Post an answer with the solution instead.

Comment: Please don't put SOLVED in the question title. You should put the solution in the window below called **Your Answer**.  This is how this question answer site works. After the required wait period accept your answer as the correct one by putting the green check mark (✅) on its left margin. This will help others.